# Why is awk removing the first character/s?

Tags: bash, awk

I issue a strange behavior.
I try to create a script but awk is removing my first character(s), and I don't know why.
Of course this code, right now is useless, but I can't continue with this strange issue ...

```
#!/bin/bash

for entry in TF5*; do
        if [[ ! $entry =~ ".desc" ]] ; then

                awk '
                BEGIN {print "BEGIN" }
                { print $0 " "}
                END { print " - DONE -" }
                ' < $entry


        fi
done
```

Output :

```
BEGIN


 ort      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
 i1/0/2   v5.7-TF5-XXXXXXXXX connected    10         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i1/0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i1/0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i1/0/5   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i1/0/6   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i1/0/7   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 e1/0/1   *** MOG2SWXXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full    10G 10GBase-SR
 i2/0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i2/0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i2/0/5   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i2/0/6   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i2/0/7   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 e2/0/1   *** MOG2SWXXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full    10G 10GBase-SR
 o1       *** SW1+2-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full    10G
 o4       *** TF5-NAXXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000
 o6       *** TF5-NAXXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000
 o7       *** TF5-NAXXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000
 - DONE -
```

If I change `{ print $0 " "}` by `{ print $0 "   "}` for example
The new output is :

```
BEGIN


   t      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
   /0/2   v5.7-TF5-FXXXXXXXX connected    10         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/5   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/6   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/7   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/1   *** MOG2SWXXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full    10G 10GBase-SR
   /0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/5   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/6   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/7   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
   /0/1   *** MOG2SWXXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full    10G 10GBase-SR
          *** SW1+2-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full    10G
          *** TF5-NAXXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000
          *** TF5-NAXXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000
          *** TF5-NAXXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000
 - DONE -
```

The real file:

```
cat -e TF5_MOG2_SW2-EU-A50R1-DC7-1
^M$
^M$
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type^M$
Gi1/0/2   v5.7-TF5-FXXXXXXXX connected    10         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Gi1/0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Gi1/0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Gi1/0/5   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Gi1/0/6   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Gi1/0/7   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Te1/0/1   *** MOG2SWXXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full    10G 10GBase-SR^M$
Gi2/0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Gi2/0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Gi2/0/5   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Gi2/0/6   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Gi2/0/7   v8.12-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^M$
Te2/0/1   *** MOG2SWXXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full    10G 10GBase-SR^M$
Po1       *** SW1+2-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full    10G ^M$
Po4       *** TF5-NAXXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 ^M$
Po6       *** TF5-NAXXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 ^M$
Po7       *** TF5-NAXXXXXXXX connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 ^M$
```

Comment: If you want to remove DOS symbols from a file, just use `dos2unix`. See some explanation in http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/03/different-ways-to-delete-m-character-in.html

Comment: Definitely get rid of those Ctl-M's.  It looks like when the output gets to the Ctl-M, which is a carriage return, it repositions to the front of the line and then prints the spaces, overwriting what were previously the first characters. (You can try `print $0 "XXX"` and see if you get X's at the beginning of the line.)

Comment: why using redirection in awk ? use file directly as argument, this avoid piping and shell interpretation. Is the result the same without your `<` ?

Comment: Thank you @fedorqui and @jas
A single `for entry in TF5*; do sed -i 's/^M//g' $entry; done` fix it. Becarful of ^M (you have to type CONTROL V + CONTRL M)

Comment: You're welcome. And excellent job using the `cat -e` option to show your input. Without that hint this mystery could have been much more difficult to solve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk is NOT removing the 1st character - the embedded CR is the problem - the SHELL interprets it as the instruction to 'go to position one on this line'...

Note - tested on Linux system - not sure what OS you are working with...

```
## note the ^MS represents a non-printable character; function below is for illustration  
function show_test_data { ## which included real'^MS'
cat << EOM
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Gi1/0/2   v5.7-TF5-FXXXXXXXX connected    10         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^MS
Gi1/0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^MS
Gi1/0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX^MS
EOM
}
##
function show_data {
cat $entry
}
###
function stars {
printf "\n\t## $@ ##\n"
}
###
stars "No change"
show_data | \
         awk 'BEGIN {print "BEGIN" } { print $0 " "} END { print " - DONE -" } '
stars " Change CR to Hash "
show_data | tr '\r' '#' | \
         awk 'BEGIN {print "BEGIN" } { print $0 " "} END { print " - DONE -" } '
stars " Remove CR"
show_data | tr -d '\r' | \
         awk 'BEGIN {print "BEGIN" } { print $0 " "} END { print " - DONE -" } '
stars
```

### Sample run ##

```
        ## No change ##
BEGIN
 ort      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
 i1/0/2   v5.7-TF5-FXXXXXXXX connected    10         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i1/0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 i1/0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 - DONE -

        ##  Hash  ##
BEGIN
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type#
Gi1/0/2   v5.7-TF5-FXXXXXXXX connected    10         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX#
Gi1/0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX#
Gi1/0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX#
 - DONE -

        ##  Remove CR ##
BEGIN
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Gi1/0/2   v5.7-TF5-FXXXXXXXX connected    10         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/3   v5.22-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    210        a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/4   v6.34-TF5-XXXXXXXX connected    trunk        full   1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
 - DONE -
```

:)
Dale